# passing Int (number) from tableViewCell to new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

This is kinda goofy but I have a custom tableViewCell that has a UIScrollView and pageControl. Everything works fine, though I can't figure out how to send/pass "pageControll.currentPage" that is being updated within the UITableViewCell to my ViewImageViewController.

I am not using "didSelectRowAtIndexPath". Each cell has it's indepentent varying image scrollView and pageControl.

TableViewCell: Works perfectly

```
class FriendsFeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) { //current page: works
    let currentPage = (CGFloat(imageScrollView.contentOffset.x) / CGFloat(userImageView!.frame.size.width))
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
}
```

Height for Cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 470
}
```

TableViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell: FriendsFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell

//Grabbing array of images from master Image Array
//images array will vary 1-3: as of now
let images = masterImageArray[indexPath.row]

//ScrollView setup
let scrollView = cell.imageScrollView
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
scrollView.tag = indexPath.row

//setup the image array for scrollView
var imageViews = [UIImageView]()
imageViews.append(cell.imageView_1)
imageViews.append(cell.imageView_2)
imageViews.append(cell.imageView_3)

//hidding all ImageViews: will only show if needed
cell.imageView_1.hidden = true
cell.imageView_2.hidden = true
cell.imageView_3.hidden = true


//tells how many pages will be need
for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ {
    imageViews[i].image = images[i]
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 310 * (i + 1), height: 400)
    cell.pageControl.numberOfPages = (i + 1) // tells how many pages
    imageViews[i].hidden = false
}

//button: Tells which image in indexPath we want to view
cell.tapToViewButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.tapToViewButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

return cell
}
```

In my TableViewViewController I'm using a button that once clicked it fires the preforemSegueWithIdentifier

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    imageSenderTag = sender.tag        
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewImageVC", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toViewImageVC"){
        let viewImageVC: ViewImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewImageViewController

        //moves [image] to next VC
        viewImageVC.imageArrayToPass = masterImageArray[imageSenderTag]
        //FIXME: need to pass "currentPage" (Int) to newViewController
    }
}
```

I've can't figure this out. I've search but everyone is using "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" which I am not using.

**EDIT:----------------**

I've tried to incorporate both the recommendation of @ozgur and @Mundi but it didn't work.

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewImageVC", sender: sender)
}
```

tried: @ozgur recommendation

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "toViewImageVC") {
        let viewImageVC: ViewImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewImageViewController
        viewImageVC.mainUserImageToPass = masterUserPicsArray[imageSenderTag]
        viewImageVC.imageArrayToPass = masterImageArray[imageSenderTag]

        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: button.tag, inSection: 0)
            let cell = resultsTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

                  //ERROR
            ***viewImageVC.pageNumber = cell!.pageControl.currentPage***
        }

    }
}
```

ERROR: Value of type "UITableViewCell" has no member 'pageControl'

UITableViewCell, certainly has a pageControl. why would this be happening? It's referencing that cells info, right?

TRIED: @Mundi's recommendation

```
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let point = button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.resultsTable)
    let indexPath = self.resultsTable.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!

    let idx = indexPath.row // use this for accessing your image view array

    if (segue.identifier == "toViewImageVC") {
        let viewImageVC: ViewImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewImageViewController
        viewImageVC.mainUserImageToPass = masterUserPicsArray[idx]
        viewImageVC.pageNumber = (sender?.tag)! // EXIBIT: A
    }
```

The pageNumber that is sent to the ViewImageViewController sends the indexPath.row of the cell and not the current page of the UIScrollView in the indexPath.row

Comment: Which cell's `pageControl.currentPage` do you want to pass to destination view controller once the button was pressed?

Comment: It depends what cell the user is currently viewing and want to view in detail. So, pageControl.tag = indexPath.row

Comment: Wait a second, so each cell has its own pageControl and only one cell takes up the entire screen at a time? How do you set button's `tag` property? Can you show us your entire code to let us understand your logic better?

Comment: It's updated. so there a Image scroll view in cell that varies in size. So the user scrolls up/down the tableView and scrolls left/right if he/she wants to see more pics posted by that user. If the user wants to view a particular image in detail, he/she presses a button to view it in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only one section in your table view;

First, you can pass UIButton pressed as the sender of segue in `buttonPressed:` method:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {    
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewImageVC", sender: sender)
}
```

Secondly, you can get the cell that the button belongs to using its `tag` value in `prepareForSegue` method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if let button = sender as? UIButton {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: button.tag, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FriendsFeedTableViewCell
    ...
    viewImageVC.currentPage = cell!.pageControl.currentPage
  }
}
```

If you have multiple sections; you can obtain `indexPath` described by [@Mundi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511721/793428):

```
let point = button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
```

Comment: My man! It works!! Strange how the cell needs to be specified in this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`, pass `sender: sender`. Make sure that you set the `tag` to the current page.

In `prepareForSegue` you now have access to your `Int`as follows:

```
let button = sender as! UIButton
let point = button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
let idx = indexPath.row // use this for accessing your image view arrays
viewImageVC.currentPage = sender.tag
```

Comment: hi Mundi, I tried your code (above) but the "viewImageVC.currentPage" is the indexPath.row or the cell number.

Comment: Thanks you for the response Mundi, by including the cell in your code and later getting the pageControl.currentPage did eventually work.

Comment: Good for you. In general, though, it is **very bad practice** to rely on the view hierarchy to extract data for the next controller. It violates the **[MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)** model and could break any time.